# 親アプリがterminatedの際にopenparentapplicationが作動しない件

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

現在AppleWatchアプリの開発を行っています。
WatchKitのopenparentapplicationを利用してiPhone側でプッシュ通知を送る機能を実装しているのですが、iPhoneの状態がフォアグラウンドもしくはバックグラウンドで動いている場合しか動作しません。アプリがterminatedの状態でもopenparentapplicationメソッドを使えばiPhone側ではアプリがバックグラウンドで起動されるとリファレンスには書いてあるのですがうまくいきません。何かアドバイスをいただけると幸いです。

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {

    self.backgroundTaskIdentifier =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithName(
            "MyTask",
            expirationHandler: {
                print("Background task is expired now")
        })

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        //長めの処理
}
```

Comment: アプリが terminated の時、 `application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:` は呼び出されたが、その中で PFPush の`sendPush:` しようとするとエラーになる、ということでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。いろいろとテストしてみたところアプリがterminatedの時には文字列の受け渡しなど単純な作業であっても`application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:` が作動しておりませんでした。

Comment: ということはPFPushは関係なさそうですね。タイトル・本文・サンプルコードを「terminated状態で`application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply`が呼ばれない」という点に絞った方が、より質問が分かりやすくなると思います。まだ他の方から回答等されていませんから編集しちゃってもいいかと。

Comment: そうですね。編集します。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

遅いレスで恐縮ですが、私もこの件でかなり悩みましたが、結局解決することができませんでした。まわりのハイスキルなエンジニアさんたちも同じことを言ってましたので、おそらくopenParentApplicationにはバグがあったのではないかと思います。

watchOS2のWatchConnectivityを使い始めましたが、こちらは今のところいい感じで動いてますので、今後はこちらを使い、既存ユーザーにはなるべく早くwatchOS2へのアップデートをお願いするのが得策かと思います。

ちなみに、私のwatchOS1アプリをwatchOS2へ対応させたときのログをもとに、[Qiitaにtips](http://qiita.com/sassymanyuichi/items/ed32c5a10bdc1b799c6a)を書きましたので、もしよければご参考にされて下さい。